# My site has only one page, and users access my uploaded mp3 files from there - can I analyze access by song title?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

My site is Abracadenza.ca. I upload mp3 files to the media library. I then create ‘posts’ which display the songs on my home page. Each song is categorized using a number of categories, eg composer, voice (soprano, alto, tenor, bass). Users zero in on their song by filtering via categories. I use an analytics plugin which gives me user info (geographic, device and browser, referrer, page visited), and sometimes it shows a bit more. But I’d like to know which song they select. Can I do this?

Comment: Sounds like a job for Google Tags - or you can write code that records, with a use profile, which songs they downloaded.  Your question is really broad.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect class "track-content title" when someone play any of the music using google tag manager.

you can link analytics plugin for precise details.

https://www.lovesdata.com/blog/google-tag-manager-button-click-tracking

You can also add a post-id in each post i.e. music track containers for a better analytics result.